# InputMismatchException reading from file with mixed data using nextDouble()

Tags: java

Here is my current code for a panel I am building for an application:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BookListPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JList<String> bookList;
    private String[] list = new String[20];
    private double[] priceList = new double[7];
    private File priceFile = new File("BookPrices.txt");
    int counter = 0;

    public BookListPanel() throws FileNotFoundException, InputMismatchException
    {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(priceFile).useDelimiter(",\\s|$|\\n");
        while(fileReader.hasNext())
        {
            list[counter] = fileReader.next();
            priceList[counter] = fileReader.nextDouble();
            counter++;
        }

        bookList = new JList<>(list);
        bookList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(bookList);
    }
}
```

I am trying to read a file with mixed information, here it is for reference:

```
I Did It Your Way, 11.95
The History of Scotland, 14.50
Learn Calculus in One Day, 29.95
Feel the Stress, 18.50
Great Poems, 12.95
Europe on a Shoestring, 10.95
The Life of Mozart, 14.50
```

I am receiving an InputMismatchException at the nextDouble line when I try to build my application:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at BookListPanel.<init>(BookListPanel.java:26)
    at BookstoreGUI.<init>(BookstoreGUI.java:39)
    at Bookstore.main(Bookstore.java:13)
```

I've been trying to troubleshoot the issue, and have resorted to taking out the nextDouble line and just reading straight into the String array and printing it out with the counter number like this:

```
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(priceFile).useDelimiter(",\\s|$|\\n");
    while(fileReader.hasNext())
    {
        list[counter] = fileReader.next();
        System.out.println(counter + ": " + list[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
```

and I receive this input:

```
0: I Did It Your Way
1: 11.95

2: The History of Scotland
3: 14.50

4: Learn Calculus in One Day
5: 29.95

6: Feel the Stress
7: 18.50

8: Great Poems
9: 12.95

10: Europe on a Shoestring
11: 10.95

12: The Life of Mozart
13: 14.50
14:
```

This leads me to believe that even though I have the newline expression in my delimiter list, it's still including it whenever it is reading the double (because there is an extra line added after the number has been read). I am wondering if there is something I am excluding or missing that could eliminate that newline so that I can read the number into the double array, or maybe it's something I am missing completely?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried printing out what the line that you're trying to consume with `fileReader.nextDouble()` should be?

Comment: I'll try to print out the line that I'm trying to read with fileReader.nextDouble() and post back, thanks for the input. Also unfortunately I am using JCreator LE and it does not have a debugger. doh!

Comment: Would I just put another `fileReader.nextLine()` in between `list[counter] = fileReader.next();` and `priceList[counter] = fileReader.nextDouble();`? Also, just ran it slightly differently with a conditional statement and the only number nextDouble read was the last one in the file without a line break. Sorry, the issue has me completely confused.

Comment: If I have a new line as a delimiter why isn't it ignored going from token to token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you defined your delimited does not work. And you have whitespace in your Strings (like in `"I Did It Your Way"`).

This works:

```
useDelimiter("[,$\\v]\\s*")
```

Explanation:

- match one of: `,`, `$` or vertical whitespace (line separators)
- then match zero or more whitespace (since Strings and doubles are separated by `",␠"`)